# Alexa Skills - how to return an intent with slot values from another intent?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

How to return an intent with slot values from another intent?

I want to trigger an intent by returning a slot value of it in another intent.

Here is example of my JSON file:

```
{
  "interactionModel": {
    "languageModel": {
      "invocationName": "movie antakshari",
      "intents": [
        {
          "name": "SchoolIntent",
          "slots": [
            {
              "name": "Subject",
              "type": "subjects"
            }
          ],
          "samples": ["{subjects}"]
        },
        {
          "name": "teachersIntent",
          "slots": [],
          "samples": ["teachers"]
        },
      ],
      "types": [
        {
          "name": "subjects",
          "values": [
            {
              "name": {"value": "maths"}
            },
            {
              "name": {"value": "english"}
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my index.js file :

```
const teacherIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
&& handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'teacherIntent';
    },

    handle(handlerInput) {
        if (some condition) {
            // Here I want to return the schoolIntentHandler with a slot value maths
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to trigger schoolIntentHandler from teacherIntent?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by [ElicitIntent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/lambda-input-response-format.html#using-lambda-response-format). But when you elicit your intent your slots for the particular intent will get clear(reset to null). To overcome this, before eliciting intent put your slot value into session attribute in a unique way to identify this as a slot one like **SLOT_key**. And when it enters into the desired intent get the slot value from session attribue & use it for your logic.

Answer (score 0):

The intent invocation is driven by Users utterance. A User has to say something so that Alexa Service can match what user said to an intent in your model.

In your case, you need to make user to invoke schoolIntent by guiding him properly. i.e. **You need to return a speech from here that will make user to utter something that matches schoolIntent**

```
handle(handlerInput) {
    if (some condition) {
        // Here I want to return the schoolIntentHandler with a slot value maths
        //
        // You need to return a speech from here that will make user to utter something that matches schoolIntent.
    }
}
```